# Google Maps JS Api - b.get is not a function error(isLocationOnEdge)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typeerror

I want to check if there is a marker on my route.. So i tried to use isLocationOnEdge() and i am getting "TypeError:b.get is not a function" error.
Here is my code i tried several changes but couldn't fix the problem.

```
      var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
      directionsService.route({
      origin: my_position.getPosition(),
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(my_markers[0][0],my_markers[0][1]),
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
      var isLocationOnEdge = google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge;
      var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
      for (var i = 0; i < my_markers.length; i++) {
      if (isLocationOnEdge(new google.maps.LatLng(my_markers[i][0],my_markers[i][1]),path))
          {
              console.log("Its in!")
          }
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly), the `isLocationOnEdge` method takes the following arguments:

> **isLocationOnEdge(point:LatLng, poly:Polygon|Polyline, tolerance?:number)**
> Return Value:  boolean
> Computes whether the given point lies on or near to a polyline, or the edge of a polygon, within a specified tolerance. Returns true when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance. The tolerance defaults to 10-9 degrees.

The `overview_path` is not a `google.maps.Polyline` (or a Polygon), it is an array of `google.maps.LatLng` objects.

If I use that path to create a polyline, it works for me

```
var isLocationOnEdge = google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge;
var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: path
})
if (isLocationOnEdge(new google.maps.LatLng(37.438442, -122.157558), polyline, 1e-3)) {
  console.log("Its in!")
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/Lt7ouj8w/3/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: [{
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [{
          visibility: 'off'
        }]
      }]
    });

  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: "Palo Alto, CA",
      destination: "Stanford, CA",
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
      var isLocationOnEdge = google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge;
      var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path
      })
      if (isLocationOnEdge(new google.maps.LatLng(37.438442, -122.157558), polyline, 1e-3)) {
        console.log("Its in!")
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.438442, -122.157558),
          icon: {
            url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
            size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.5, 3.5)
          },
          title: "On Route"
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "on route"
        });
        infowindow.open(map, mark);
      }
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```